# How to dynamically change bootstrap modal body

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

So I have Bootstrap modal defined as:

```
   <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Error</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p> </p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And I want to edit the empty body with jscript. Im a beginner in Javascript so I'll appreciate the simplest answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this one:

```
$('.modalShow').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var e = $(this);
    var title = e.data('title');
    var body = e.data('value');
    $('.modal-title').html(title);
    $('.modal-body').html(body);
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
});
```

Comment: this is not correct you are using `#` whereas there is `class` instead of `id` with the names modal-title, modal-body

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam Thanks for your valuable suggestion. We can change respective `class` to `id` so there is no big deal for it.

Answer (score 17):

Please have a look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ramanbedi1989/obs3Lf9x/) fiddle.

Here is the code:

```
$(function(){
  $('.custom-modal').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var mymodal = $('#myModal');
    mymodal.find('.modal-body').text('hello');
    mymodal.modal('show');

  });
})
```

Answer (score 3):

the simplest solution is - you can use javascript's `innerHTML` to change html of your modal body like this -

```
//get your modal body by class and change its html
document.getElementByClass("modal-body").innerHTML = "<p>some text</p>";
```

Comment: when the modal is hidden it throws 'cannot access innerHTML of null' or something like that

Answer (score 0):

I have done this in C# as follows.

**C# :**

```
System.Text.StringBuilder stringBuilder = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        stringBuilder.Append(@"<script language='javascript'>");
        stringBuilder.Append(@"$('#errorModal').find('.modal-body').text('"+ your error message + "');");
        stringBuilder.Append(@"$('#errorModal').modal('show');");
        stringBuilder.Append(@"</script>");
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "JSScript", stringBuilder.ToString());
```

**HTML :**

```
    <div class="modal fade" id="errorModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p> </p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```